# Sparql Query at endpoint

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sparql

I want to run the following sparql query at an endpoint:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?name WHERE{?person foaf:name ?name.FILTER regex(str(?name), "+ns+","i")}
```

I'm coding in C# on Visual Studio, and would send this query to the endpoint. It should check the results without any case-senstivity, but writing the query this way gives an error in visual studio. How do I correct it?

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update (based on author's clarification that "i" is where the problem lies):

You need to properly escape the " symbol so that it gets included in the SPARQL query string. Currently the ["] before [i] signals the end of the text string. No wonder you get an error message.

See [MSDN: String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for escaping rules:

- either " escape as \" or make the string a C# verbatim literal and escape as ""

---

Check DotNetRdf documentation for [Querying with SPARQL examples](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Querying%20with%20SPARQL).

It shows both how to run SPARQL queries (using DotNetRdf) and how to inject variable values into queries (what you are trying to do with "+ns+" and "i").

Also:

- [answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com) is a good place to ask Semantic Web / RDF / SPARQL questions
- please describe the error you are getting (what Ren asked in comments above)

Comment: "i" gives an error in visual studio,it says the variable doesn't exist,expects a ;
my aim is to just send the query to the endpoint and it performs a case insensitive search!!